# Content type 'application/json' not supported in Spring MVC on POST

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

im trying to parse a simple object in a POST method but I'm always getting this error:

```
2017-02-23 03:52:45 DEBUG AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver:133 - Resolving exception from handler [com.dlo.food.controller.Lists@40079d7e]: org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/json' not supported
2017-02-23 03:52:45 DEBUG ResponseStatusExceptionResolver:133 - Resolving exception from handler [com.dlo.food.controller.Lists@40079d7e]: org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/json' not supported
2017-02-23 03:52:45 DEBUG DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver:133 - Resolving exception from handler [com.dlo.food.controller.Lists@40079d7e]: org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/json' not supported
```

In my **pom.xml** I've included the jackson library files:

```
...
    <properties>
        <jackson.version>2.6.3</jackson.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
...
```

And I've declared the controller this way:

```
/**
     * 
     * @param request
     * @return
     * @return
     */
    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/uiupdatepost", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<String> UIUpdatePost(@RequestBody Category category, @RequestHeader HttpServletRequest request) {
        try {
            return ResponseEntity.ok("");
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN).body(new UIError(t).toHTML());
        }
    }
```

The class category is very simple:

```
public class Category implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Category() {
        //
    }

    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String priority;
    private String categoryId;
    private String color;

    /**
    ALL GETTER AND SETTERS
    **/
}
```

If I run CURL:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"id":"1","name":"PIZZA","priority":"1","color":"","categoryId":""}' http://localhost:8080/food/uiupdatepost.html
```

I get this error:

**HTTP: 415**

I've searched all the possible solutions included:

1. Removing **consumes** attribute.
2. Checked for 2 setter with same name but different type. No, 1 setter/1 getter for all attributes.

Also tested the manual deserialization without problems:

```
    Category userFromJSON = mapper.readValue("{\"id\":\"1\",\"name\":\"PIZZA\",\"priority\":\"1\",\"color\":\"\",\"categoryId\":\"\"}", Category.class);
```

Comment: Use @RestController above your controller class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welp.. I want to cry... after hours and hours, changing :

**MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE**

for

**MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE**

worker for me.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds, that Spring wasn't able to create an appropriate HTTPMessageConverter able to parse JSON for some reason. If jackson is on the classpath - as it is as contained in your pom-xml - the converter should be registered in method `org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.addDefaultHttpMessageConverters`

I'd suggest to check, why this isn't happening. Alternatively you can configure appropriate `HttpMessageConverter` by hand. If you've a configuration class derived from `org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer` you would have something like this:

```
@Override
public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
    super.configureMessageConverters(converters);
    converters.add(new MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter());
    converters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That helped me to find the solution: that I was missing @EnableWebMvc.

Comment: Pleased to helped you ;-)